# How can I install [latest version] of youtube-dl or yt-dlp on Centos 7 ? I have been trying for the past 2 days withous success :\

Tags: installation, version, centos7, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I keep getting this id error both on youtube-dl and yt-dlp
ROR: [youtube] _8zoICtzoDs: Unable to extract uploader **id**;

I guess youtube changed format recently (video **id**) and I would like to install the adapted version of the software.
Thank you very much for any help!

I tried installing and reinstalling (updating) the software in all possible ways.

Comment: Your video ID works well for me on yt-dlp, version 2023.03.04 ; how are you calling yt-dlp, or youtube-dl? From CLI or inside a script?

Comment: A million thanks for the answer!
I found out that yt-dlp needs python3.7 (minimum) so I had to do the following steps:
>cd /tmp/
>wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
>tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
>cd Python-3.7.9
>./configure --enable-optimizations
>sudo make altinstall
>sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
It gets like this in the end: Abr  1 05:13 python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.7

Comment: Ok, happy coding then :-)